# Oracle sql. Связки записей из одной таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle

Дано: table1 с атрибутами PARENT_ID(внешний ключ на table2.ID) и ID(также внешний ключ на table2.ID), table2 с атрибутами ID и NAME

Записи в  table2 могут быть и родителями и потомками друг у друга.

к примеру в Table1 есть записи

| ID | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

в Table2 есть записи

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | дерево |
| 2 | железо |
| 3 | пластик |

Необходим запрос, показывающий все пары наименований, по связкам в table1:

| NAME | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| железо | дерево |
| дерево | железо |
| железо | пластик |

Comment: да, к примеру в таблице1 есть записи 
2           1
1           2 
2           3

в таблице 2 есть записи 
1    дерево
2    железо
3    пластик

Необходимо вывести таблицу вида:
железо          дерево
дерево          железо
железо          пластик

Comment: *Необходим запрос, показывающий все пары наименований, по связкам в table1* А где запись "дерево-пластик"? она получается по цепочке "дерево-железо-пластик"...

Comment: А что по вашему есть _пара наименований_, или по каким условиям  вы построили ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 2):

Получить все пары наименований по связям в таблице можно стандартным запросом:

```
select t1.*, t20.name rootname, t21.name, t22.name pname 
from (
    select level lvl, connect_by_root id root, sys_connect_by_path (id, '/') path, t1.* 
    from t1 connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id) t1 
join t2 t20 on t20.id = t1.root
join t2 t21 on t21.id = t1.id
join t2 t22 on t22.id = t1.parent_id
```

На данных из вопроса будет получен результат ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d1754ecb9f14b28d340cb36456046062)):

```
LVL ROOT PATH             ID  PARENT_ID ROOTNAME NAME     PNAME   
--- ---- -------- ---------- ---------- -------- -------- --------
  1    2 /2                2          3 железо   железо   пластик 
  2    2 /2/1              1          2 железо   дерево   железо  
  2    2 /2/1              1          2 железо   дерево   железо  
  1    1 /1                1          2 дерево   дерево   железо  
  1    2 /2                2          1 железо   железо   дерево  
  2    1 /1/2              2          1 дерево   железо   дерево
```

Он содержит корень и путь для каждой пары значений. Остаётся выбрать, какие из них соответствуют бизнес требованию и как должен выглядеть конечный результат.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
cte (parent_id, id) AS ( SELECT * 
                         FROM table1
                       UNION ALL
                         SELECT cte.parent_id, table1.id 
                         FROM cte
                         JOIN table1 ON cte.id = table1.parent_id
                         WHERE cte.parent_id <> table1.id )
SELECT t21.name, t22.name
FROM cte
JOIN table2 t21 ON cte.parent_id = t21.id
JOIN table2 t22 ON cte.id = t22.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48e9fedce1121e34880792c8e7e76bed